# Unable to click one by one present in image carousel with selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am unable to click on the images present in below carousel as shown in below snapshot. I tried a lot but failed though i was able to navigate to other images by clicking on the right Arrow navigation button . The Image Carousel is Present below the Featured Vehicles header Text (in website) which has navigation buttons both left and right.[image]
Site Link : https://ryder.com/used-trucks

Below is the one of the approach that I tried ,and the code is below. Please i need your help on this at the earliest.

```
public void click_Image_Carousel_To_Open_ProductDetailsPage() throws InterruptedException
{ 
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;        
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h2[contains(text(),'FEATURED VEHICLES')]")));
    
    
     WebElement ele1= null;
     String image_link = null;
     List<WebElement> image_Carousel_Links_list  = driver.findElements(By.xpath("(//div[@class='photo']/a)"));
     System.out.println("Size :"+image_Carousel_Links_list.size());
     
     WebElement  image_Carousel_Next_Btn =  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//BUTTON[@class='slick-next slick-arrow'][text()='Next']"));

     for(int i=1;i<image_Carousel_Links_list.size();i++)
     {
         System.out.println(+i+")Image links :"+driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@class='photo']/a)["+i+"]")).getAttribute("href"));
                    
         System.out.println(" Element : (//div[@class='photo']/a)["+i+"]");
         
         ele1=driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@class='photo']/a)["+i+"]"));
         
         //this for loop to rediscover the elements to avoid stale element exception
          for(int k=0;k<500;k++)
          {
              image_Carousel_Links_list  = driver.findElements(By.xpath("(//div[@class='photo']/a)"));
              
              if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@class='photo']/a)["+i+"]")).isDisplayed())
              {
                  ele1=driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@class='photo']/a)["+i+"]"));
                  break;
              }
              
              click_ImageCarousel_NextButton(image_Carousel_Next_Btn);
              Thread.sleep(300);
          }
         
         if(ele1.isDisplayed())
         {               
             ele1.click();
             System.out.println(i+") Clicked on the Image present in Image Carousel :" +ele1.getAttribute("href"));
             Thread.sleep(3000);
             driver.navigate().back();
             Thread.sleep(4000);
         }
         else
         {
           System.out.println(" Image Not found in Image Carousel");
         }
         
     }
     
}

private void click_ImageCarousel_NextButton(WebElement image_Carousel_Next_Btn) {
    
    image_Carousel_Next_Btn.click();
}
```

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. What does exactly not work? When I cklicked on an image from slideshow it does open another layer with a screenshot.

Comment: I am not able to click on images present in Image Carousel

Comment: Do you mean, that you want with selenenium frame work click on the gallery?

Comment: I just need i the code logic which will identify images present in Image Carousel at runtime and also click them. Or i am also ok with If you want to create a small project and share .

Comment: Have you tried to click using `JavaScriptExecutor`? `js.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", webElement);`

Comment: Need to Check this JavaScriptExecutor option.

Comment: @kunLun : During runtime  it returns false when my code tries to find for those images using  .isDsiplayed() method hence it doesn`t click on the image.

Comment: @BalajiSingh.Y Using js you don't need to check `isDisplayed()`, eventually you need to check if exists.